# How to put an element of a string to a vector?

Tags: c++, string, vector

I want to put specific elements of a string to a `vector<string>`.

To give you a better explanation of what i intend to do:

```
string str;
vector<string> in;

cin >> str; // input: abc

for(int i = 0;i < str.length();i++) {
       in.push_back(&str[i]);
}
```

now i want the first element of `vector<string> in` to be "a" `(in[0] = "a")`, the second to be b etc.. i want to use strings for this. Is it possible to do it because when i print the vector it gives me that first it has `abc` then `bc` and in the end only `c`?

Comment: Do you intend to always store length-1 strings? If so, it may be easier to use an `std::vector<char>`.

Comment: @juanchopanza i figured it would be easier with chars but im wondering if it is possible to do it with strings. If no one can help me with this i will probably use that. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use `std::vector<char>` or use [`substr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr).

Example 1:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::string str;
    std::vector<char> in;

    std::cin >> str; // input: abc

    for (std::string::size_type i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        in.push_back(str[i]);
    }
}
```

Or a simpler variant:

```
int main()
{
    std::string str;
    std::cin >> str; // input: abc
    std::vector<char> in(str.begin(), str.end());
}
```

Example 2:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::string str;
    std::vector<std::string> in;

    std::cin >> str; // input: abc

    for (std::string::size_type i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        in.push_back(str.substr(i, 1));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`std::string` [has a constructor that takes a integral count and a single `char`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) to instantiate a string with `n` elements of the same value. You can use this and the fact that `std::strings` is much like a container of `char`:

```
for (auto c : str)
  in.emplace_back(1ul, c);
```

Alternatively, you can store single char in the vector instead of `std::string`:

```
std::vector<char> in(str.begin(), str.end());
```